# how open mapbox map html in node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mapbox

I'm using mapbox api.
I would ultimately like to display mapbox map in node.js sever.

Only html that contains texts is working, html that contains map script isn't working.

How do I solve this problem?

(example - index.html work but mapWeb.html doesn't work in index.js)

```
[index.js]
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');

    http.createServer(function (request, response) {

        request.on('readable', function () {
            request.read(); // throw away the data
        });

        request.on('end', function () {

            response.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            });
            response.write(fs.readFileSync("./index.html"));

            response.end('Hello HTTP!');
        });

    }).listen(8080);

[index.html]
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello Node Server Routing Is Working.
    </body>
    </html>


[mapWeb.html]
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src='C:\Users\YJH\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\mapServerTest\mapServerTest\node_modules\mapbox-gl\dist\mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <link href='C:\Users\YJH\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\mapServerTest\mapServerTest\node_modules\mapbox-gl\dist\mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #map {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id='map'></div>
        <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamhqaGpoOTYiLCJhIjoiY2oxaGpjMjF2MDAydDJ2b2F5cXFlM3QwYiJ9.CDgM2v_KGqdegjs-bK-Cnw';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9', //stylesheet location
        center: [-74.50, 40], // starting position
        zoom: 9 // starting zoom
    });
        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `doesn't work` - any useful information in the *browsers* **developer** tools console?

Comment: Waiting for response from 127.0.0.1.
I think createServer doesn't work.

Comment: your "server" does this `response.write(fs.readFileSync("./index.html"));` for every request it seems